Systemd shutdown stop unit before PAM session termination
I am trying to create a systemd --user unit which is running when the first user session is started (no matter if graphical or SSH) and runs a stop command when the last user session is terminated.
I am having some success using this /etc/systemd/user/user-service.service
[Unit]
Description=Service description
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service gvfs-daemon.service
After=gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service gvfs-daemon.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/service/myservice.sh pull
ExecStop=/etc/service/myservice.sh push

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target

Then activating the unit using systemctl --global enable user-service.
The myservice.sh script essentially is doing a gvfs mount and synchronizing some files.
#!/bin/bash
...
gio mount smb://<hostname.domain.tld>/share/
...
gio mount -u smb://<hostname.domain.tld>/share/

The machine is domain joined, winbind.service is active and pam_winbind.so is enabled. During login pam_winbind.so is creating /tmp/krb5cc_<uid> properly.
The complete login procedure is working just perfectly fine.
The problem is at logout. Somehow I cannot achieve the PAM session to be terminated AFTER systemd is running the ExecStop command. Debugging shows that /tmp/krb5cc_<uid> does not exist any more when ExecStop is run and therefore the gvfs mount is failing.
I am assuming pam_winbind.so is removing krb5cc on PAM session termination.
Is there any way I can keep the PAM session open?
I have experimented with PAMname= property within the systemd unit with no success.
